# Android Eclipse, AlertDialog outside of ativity

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an AlertDialog with an OK button in my activity by using this code:

```
         alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();

        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Welcome to AndroidHive.info");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);



        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed  
    }
    });

        alertDialog.show();
```

This works fine within the application, but I want this to be ran and show even if we're outside of the application. Of course with the application still running and not closed. Much like Toast. even if I can use a Toast with an OK button I'd be happy.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a dialog as standalone. You will have to get an Activity to display your dialog. In my mind, your solution would lead to a bad user experience if every app could launch a modal dialog whenever it wants.

But you can imagine 2 solutions :

- bringing up an activity with this dialog open (maybe you could make the activity transparent) when a certain intent is sent to the system.
- use notifications, it looks quite close from what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Maybe I should explain what the app does.The app is a dictionary that gives you the meaning of a word.App also runs a service upon start.The service keeps an eye on clipboard, when a word is copied in,app then gives you the meaning of the word in a Toast.So if a word is copied in browser you can get the meaning immediately.The Toast is done in main activity,since the service passes back the word from service class to main activity. A toast appears anywhere,but not an AlertBox, we need something like a toast but with a button to give the user a chance to read.

Comment: I still consider notifications are what you are looking for. You should consider adopting it, your app will integrate smoothly in Android, providing users a better experience.